# How to avoid storing bloat output of CMD while logging the commands in log files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy, winrar

everyone.

I was using `Robocopy` and `WinRAR` in a `CMD` batch script. I was surprised to see the log file was huge and full of bloat. The `WinRAR` bloat was not that bad. However, the `Robocopy` output was so bloated. Because it copies large files (300+ GB).

Here is the `Robocopy` command that I use:

```
robocopy /Z /B /ZB /J /X /V /TS /FP /ETA /TEE /LOG+:"C:\log.txt" "D:\Data" "E:\Data"
```

Here is what the output of `Robocopy` looks like in the log file (Deleted most lines to summerize the issue):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Sunday, February 12, 2023 9:42:25 AM
   Source : D:\Data
     Dest : E:\Data

    Files : *.*
        
  Options : *.* /V /X /TS /FP /TEE /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /ZB /J /ETA /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       3    D:\Data
        Newer             39.1 m 2023/02/12 00:00:25    D:\Data\abc.iso
  0.1%
  0.2%
  0.4%
  0.5%
  0.7%
  0.8%
  1.0%
  1.1%
  1.3%
  1.4%
  1.6%
  1.7%
  1.9%
  2.0%
  2.2%
  2.3%
  2.5%
  2.6%
  2.8%
  2.9%
  3.1%
  3.2%
  3.4%
... (Deleted the lines between because they are too long)
 97.1%
 97.2%
 97.4%
 97.5%
 97.7%
 97.8%
 98.0%
 98.1%
 98.3%
 98.4%
 98.6%
 98.7%
 98.9%
 99.0%
 99.2%
 99.3%
 99.5%
 99.6%
 99.8%
 99.9%
100%
```

Here is the `WinRAR` command:

```
rar a -ag -ep -m5 -md1024m D:\compressed_data D:\data.iso -p1234 >> C:\log_compress.txt
```

And this is the output of the `WinRAR` command stored in the log file:

```
RAR 4.20   Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal   9 Jun 2012
Trial version             Type RAR -? for help

Evaluation copy. Please register.

Creating archive D:\compressed_data20230211160436.rar

Adding    D:\data.iso                     0%  1%  2%  3%  4%  5%  6%  7%  8%  9% 10% 11% 12% 13% 14% 15% 16% 17% 18% 19% 20% 21% 22% 23% 24% 25% 26% 27% 28% 29% 30% 31% 32% 33% 34% 35% 36% 37% 38% 39% 40% 41% 42% 43% 44% 45% 46% 47% 48% 49% 50% 51% 52% 53% 54% 55% 56% 57% 58% 59% 60% 61% 62% 63% 64% 65% 66% 67% 68% 69% 70% 71% 72% 73% 74% 75% 76% 77% 78% 79% 80% 81% 82% 83% 84% 85% 86% 87% 88% 89% 90% 91% 92% 93% 94% 95% 96% 97% 98% 99%  OK 
Done
```

As you can see, the percentages are bloating the log file regardless what command it occurs with. What I want to achieve is, `How can I log the commands without those unnecessary repeated percentages that are filling up the log files?`

Comment: maybe the `/NP` switch would be helpful?

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `robocopy /?` and read the output usage help carefully from top to bottom. There is also an online Microsoft documentation for [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) as well as the [ROBOCOPY.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) documentation of SS64. Next open the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* which is the manual for `Rar.exe` and read this manual also carefully, especially the description about the switch `-id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the precentage bloat from the ROBOCOPY command it is done by adding `/NP` switch. Thanks to [**@Stephan's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425688/how-to-avoid-storing-bloat-output-of-cmd-while-logging-the-commands-in-log-files?noredirect=1#comment133086063_75425688) for resolving this issue.

```
robocopy /NP /LOG+:"C:\log.txt" "D:\Data" "E:\Data"
```

To remove the precentage bloat from the WinRAR command it is done by adding `-idp` switch. Thanks to [**@Mofi's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425688/how-to-avoid-storing-bloat-output-of-cmd-while-logging-the-commands-in-log-files?noredirect=1#comment133086262_75425688) for resolving this issue.

```
rar a -idp D:\compressed_data D:\data.iso >> C:\log_compress.txt
```